# Is there a way to dynamically add a class to another class in LESS?

Tags: less, glyphicons

Here's my situation: I have a table in which every row has a `glyphicon-remove` button, which is used to deactivate a record.  When the table is read, the deactivated record has an `.inActive` class, which our LESS uses to mark text as red and strikethrough in the table.  Well, I also want the `glyphicon-remove` element to be `disabled` as well.  So, in our LESS file for the `inActive` class, we have this:

```
@RedWarning: red;

.inActive td:not(.commandColumn) {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: @RedWarning;
}
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
.inActive .glyphicon-remove {
    /* me.AddClass('.disabled'); */
}
```

So that, in the end, if the `tr` has the class `inActive`, every `glyphicon-remove` on that row automatically becomes `glyphicon-remove disabled`.  I know that I can do this in jQuery, but we have all kinds of tables throughout the system, and I want to be able to just make the change in one place.

I was looking at the `:extend` functionality, or just inheriting the class like this:

```
.inActive .glyphicon-remove {
    .disabled;
}
```

...but that returns errors saying that LESS can't find the .disabled class.

Comment: It all depends on what is that `.disabled` is supposed to do. Obviously you can't use CSS to add a style *class* to a HTML element (like you'd do with `me.AddClass('.disabled');` or so). So with CSS (and thus Less) you can only add the corresponding CSS properties to `.inActive .glyphicon-remove`.

Comment: For example if your button actually uses Bootstrap styles - then the properties of interest would be those of [`.btn.disabled`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/less/buttons.less#L46) (i.e. `.inActive .glyphicon-remove {.btn.disabled}`) or so.